# How to define a new reference frame

Tags: drake

I'd like to define a reference frame that isn't necessarily attached to a body in Drake but can still be updated during simulation with a LeafSystem. I tried using the AddFrame method described here (https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.multibody.parsing.html), but this returned an `AddFrame(): incompatible function arguments` error. I could get this error to go away by instantiating a `FixedOffsetFrame` first, but don't know if/how to update the frame's pose once it's been created. How can I create a reference frame that can be updated during simulation?

Also as a side note: I think it needs to be a frame and not just a RigidTransform since I'd like to use it with the CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame in the `MultibodyPlant` should be attached (rigidly) to some body frame.  You can specify e.g. the frame of the hand relative to the wrist.  As the joint angles change, then the location of your frame will change (during simulation).  This would be accomplished, as you say, with a `FixedOffsetFrame`.

It sounds like you want a frame that can move independently from any body/link during simulation?  Then how will you specify its pose?  If you want the `MultibodyPlant` kinematics engine to do it for you, then you would accomplish that by adding a body, with joints or a floating base (which the kinematics/dynamics engine uses) and using that as your frame.  Or you can simply keep track of a frame yourself by having a pose (relative to a body or world) in your controller/perception system/etc.

Comment: I was looking to create a frame that could move independently from any body or link where I could specify the pose within a controller, but needed it to be a frame and not just a pose because I wanted to use it as the reference frame when computing the Jacobian. I ended up creating a link for it (with no mass or collision) and set the pose using the `SetFreeBodyPose` function which seemed to do the trick - thanks!